# How to transform a copy of the original table with Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

I'm totally new to Power BI. I want to transform a table but a copy of my original table, not the original table.

My Power BI Desktop is in French, so please excuse me if I don't provide the correct English wording.

First, I know how to make a copy of my original table. I go to "Modelization" -> "New table" and I type "MyDataCopy = MyData".

Then I go to "Welcome" ("Accueil" in French, perhaps the translation is "Home" rather than "Welcome"), and I select "Transform data". Here I do my transformations. But that's always the original table MyData which appears, and even if I rename it before doing the transformations, the original table MyData is replaced with the transformed table when I click "Close and apply", with the new name.

How to do the transformations to "MyDataCopy" instead?

I'm sure it's pretty easy, sorry for the newbie question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I've found!

In the Query editor, which opens when I click "Transform data", I can right-click on "MyData" and duplicate it. Then I perform the transformations on the duplicated data.

Comment: You are correct! The first option you mentioned in your post simply creates a DAX copy of the table, but it does not make provisions to load an additional table into the data model that you can transform within Power Query.